# Laravel 5.4 Error: NotReadableException: Image source not readable

Tags: laravel, image-resizing, intervention

I'm trying to create multiple copies of profile pic in different sizes when a profile is created. But I am constantly getting this error:

" NotReadableException: Image source not readable"

Can somebody point me what I'm missing in my below code:

```
public function updateprofile(UserProfileRequest $request){
    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $profile = UserProfile::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->first();
    $profile->fullname = $request->fullname;

    if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
        if($request->file('img')->isValid()) {
            $types = array('_original.', '_32.', '_64.', '_128.');
            $sizes = array( '32', '64', '128');
            $targetPath = 'public/uploads/'.$user_id;

            try {
                $file = $request->file('img');
                $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fName = time();
                $original = $fName . array_shift($types) . $ext;
                Storage::putFileAs($targetPath, $file, $original);

                foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
                    $newName = $fName . $type . $ext;
                    Storage::copy($targetPath . $original, $targetPath . $newName);
                    $newImg = Image::make($targetPath . $newName);
                    $newImg->resize($sizes[$key], null, function($constraint){
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                    $newImg->save($targetPath . $newName);
                }

                $profile->img = 'public/uploads/'.$user_id;
            } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {
            }
        }
    }

    $profile->save();}
```

Comment: Can you post the form in your view that is submitting this request?

Comment: Here is the image upload field in the view page:
 
                        <label for="img" class="col-md-2 control-label"> Photo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">

                                {!! Form::file('img',null,array(
                                    'id'=>'img'
                                    )) !!}
                                {!! $errors->first('img') !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: do you use 'files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data" in your form?

Comment: Yes, I have used them:
{!! Form::model($profile, ['route'=>'profile','method'=>'post', 'files'=>'true', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                {!! csrf_field() !!}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it working. I made following changes to my code:

1. Use the full OS path as suggested by commanderZiltoid for the destination path.
2. Don't use `Storage::putFileAs` method to save the file. So, remove this line: `Storage::putFileAs($targetPath, $file, $original);`
3. Don't use `Storage::copy()` to copy the file, so, remove this line:
   `Storage::copy($targetPath . $original, $targetPath . $newName);`
4. For points 2 and 3, use `Image::make($file->getRealPath());` This will create the file and remember the path where the file was created. `Image->resize` method will use this path later.
5. In the end, save the relative path in the database, as here: `$profile->img = 'storage/uploads/'.$user_id.'/img/profile/'.$fName`. Since we'll use `{{ asset($profile->img) }}`, it's necessary to save only the relative path and not the absolute OS path.

   ```
   if($request->hasFile('img')) {

       if($request->file('img')->isValid()) {

           $types = array('_original.', '_32.', '_64.', '_128.'); 

           $sizes = array( array('32','32'), array('64','64'), array('128','128'));
           $targetPath = '/Users/apple/Documents/_chayyo/chayyo/storage/app/public/uploads/'.$user_id.'/img/profile/';

       try {
           $file = $request->file('img');
           $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $fName = time();
           $o_name = $fName . array_shift($types) . $ext;
           $original = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
           $original->save($targetPath . $o_name);

           foreach ($types as $key => $type) {
               $newName = $fName . $type . $ext;
               $newImg = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
               $newImg->resize($sizes[$key][0], $sizes[$key][1]);
               $newImg->save($targetPath . $newName);
           }

           $profile->img = 'storage/uploads/'.$user_id.'/img/profile/'.$fName;

       } 
        catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {

       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue i ran this command and it worked

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command creates a storage directory under the public folder.

Also use public path function to get the public path

```
$targetPath = public_path('storage/uploads/'. $user_id);
```

The 'storage' used inside the laravel public_path() function is used to get the storage main folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the path which is provided should be the absolute filepath on your server. For example instead of:

```
$targetPath = 'public/uploads/'.$user_id;
```

Use (your actual path will vary depending on your configuration)

```
$targetPath = '/var/www/sitename/public/uploads/'.$user_id;
```

Laravel also contains a helper function called [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-public-path) which can be used to obtain the "fully qualified path to the public directory". This would allow you to use something such as:

```
$targetPath = public_path('uploads/'. $user_id);
```

Also, on this line, do not forget to place a slash before the new filename:

```
$newImg = Image::make($targetPath . '/' . $newName);
```

I would also confirm that the user executing the script (if apache or nginx usually www-data unless altered) has write permissions to your `public/uploads/` directory